# Question with Vectors and Space

Tags: vectors

I always thought vectors were points in space for example a position vector which always have a direction,but know when I study vectors in mathematics its like anything can be a vector, solution to a linear equation which is a ordered pair is a vector ,list of weights of a person is a vector, anything is a vector? I thought that vectors were supposed to have a direction in space and they werent just an array of numbers. Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937464/in-linear-algebra-what-is-a-vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Linear Algebra, what is a vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937464/in-linear-algebra-what-is-a-vector)

Comment: Vector is as vector does. If you can add two of them, and multiply each of them by scalars, then they're vectors.